# How can I check the commit message of AOSP

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 4.3-jelly-bean, aosp

There is a bug in Android 4.3 and it is said to have been fixed in Android 4.4.

How can I know how it is fixed?

https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/36985755

Update 2018/03/01:

I searched with the keyword "mCurMethod" in gerrit and seems to find the related changes to fix it.

It is the commit. https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/base/+/68103

But IMHO, it is not merged into master because of merge conflicts.

How do we know how AOSP fixes it?

Git log in framework/base seems a lot of commit and is hard to locate the specific commit.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Issuetracker offers an easy way to know the status of an issue: the sidebar.

Like any other issue tracking software, there are many different statuses an issue can be in.
To help clarify the status even more, there is a switch that tells whether or not an issue has been resolved and the changes are in "production" (ie. the current codebase of the project)

For your [specific issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/36985755), the status is as follows:

```
Status
Won't Fix (Obsolete)
...
In Prod
(off)
```

This means that the issue hasn't been solved and will never be solved. It's probably not an issue anymore.

Comment: I think the issue once exists cause I met it before. And I found a possible commit for it (plz see my update) but it seems to be rejected because of merge conflicts. So how can I know how AOSP solves the issue.